# Traceview doesn't work

Tags: android, android-traceview

My Android SDK is installed here `D:\android-sdk-windows\tools`
I set all environment variables to `tools` and `platform-tools`.

When I type `traceview` to cmd, it reports.

```
C:\Users\HIEUGIOI>D:\android-sdk-windows\tools\traceview.bat
Usage: java com.android.traceview.MainWindow [-r] trace
  -r   regression only
```

How to fix ?

Is there other ways to use traceview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to supply a command-line parameter, the path to the trace log you generated from DDMS or by using `Debug.startMethodTracing()`. See [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html#runningtraceview) for more about using Traceview.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use

```
traceview -r [applicationpath+applicationname.apk]
```

Answer (score 1):

try replacing `javaCmd="java"` in your `tools/traceview` with :

```
javaCmd="/path/tojava/bin/java"
```